# How to prove $A \cong \langle a \rangle \oplus A / \langle a \rangle $ for abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $a \in A$. 
I am trying to prove 
$$ A \cong  \langle a \rangle  \oplus A / \langle  a  \rangle $$
where $\langle a \rangle $ is the subgroup generated by $a$. 
I would appreciate a proof of this fact. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\langle 2 \rangle\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ since the second group has torsion and not $\mathbb{Z}$.