# Extending a map $\langle a \rangle \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for $A$ an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups

In an exercise I am doing I have an abelian group $A$ and $a \in A$. 
I have to find a homomorphism
$$
f: \langle a \rangle \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
$$
such that $f(a) \neq 0$
and then extend this map to 
$$
f': A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}. 
$$

I was trying to prove this by considering [How to prove $A \cong \langle a \rangle \oplus A / \langle a \rangle $ for abelian group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661377/how-to-prove-a-cong-langle-a-rangle-oplus-a-langle-a-rangle-for-abeli), but this seems to be not the right approach... I would appreciate explanation on how I can do this. Thank you.

Comment: Zorn's lemma${}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.